# How to apply multiple formatting methods at the same time, e.g."1,234,567,890" and "12-3456-7890" to "1,2-34,56-7,890"

Tags: c++, string, formatting, string-formatting, stdstring

for example, if I want to convert "1234567890" to "1,234,567,890", I can use:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string st="1234567890";
    for(int i=st.length()-3;i>0;st.insert(i,","),i-=3);
    printf("%s\n",st.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

and if I want to convert "1234567890" to "12-3456-7890", just replace the for loop as :

```
for(int i=st.length()-4;i>0;st.insert(i,"-"),i-=4);
```

but the problem is, it can apply 1 format method only,and this formatting method is sequential, if I apply 2 for loops together, e.g.:

```
for(int i=st.length()-3;i>0;st.insert(i,","),i-=3);
for(int i=st.length()-4;i>0;st.insert(i,"-"),i-=4);
```

the output is 1-,234-,567-,890 but not "1,2-34,56-7,890", what is the generic way to do this?

Or in simpler words, I want a program that can:

```
1. insert "," for every 3 characters
2. insert "-" for every 4 characters
3. insert ":" for every 7 characters
.
.
.
```

which can add insert conditions in generic way, what is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using several loops, you can just use one loop, decremental by 1, with conditional insert. For example:

```
string st="1234567890";
int originalLength = st.length();
for(int i=originalLength-1;i>0;i--)
{
    int positionFromEnd = originalLength - i;

    if (positionFromEnd % 3 == 0)
        st.insert(i,",");


    if (positionFromEnd % 4 == 0)
        st.insert(i,"-");

    if (positionFromEnd % 5 == 0)
        st.insert(i,":");

    // add more condition here as need be
}

printf("%s\n", st.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for you, ignore anything that is not a number, in each pass:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void insert_delimeter(string& st, string delimeter, int interval) {
    for (int i = st.length() - 1, counter = 0; i > 0; i--) {
        if (st[i] >= '0' && st[i] <= '9')
            ++counter;
        if (counter == interval) {
            st.insert(i,delimeter);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    string st = "1234567890";
    insert_delimeter(st, ",", 3);
    insert_delimeter(st, "-", 4);
    printf("%s\n", st.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

The outcome is

```
1,2-34,56-7,890
```

Answer (score -1):

add one more counter to the first for loop

```
int num=0;
for(int i=st.length()-3;i>0;st.insert(i,","),i-=3)
num++;

for(int i=st.length()-4 + num ;i>0;st.insert(i,"-"),i-=4)
num++;
```

what happens here is num gets incremented everytime an insert takes place thus it helps to get correct string length in the next string update. which you can use to insert more symbols.